# Non-Selected Object Keys Still Showing in Dope Sheet

Tags: armature, bones, keyframes, dopesheet, actions

[image]

Hello! Would anybody happen to know why this bone/control continues to show keys after enabling "Show Selected Objects" only?

I have tried swapping in and out of Object mode, restarted, and reset my prefs and still can't figure out why this happens.

I've noticed after some time spent with other rigs working on an animation, this will eventually happen with some controls. My suspicion is that is might have something to do with the action?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if -- in the 3D Viewer -- you use the menu *Select* >> *None*?  Select menu is between View and Pose menus.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: The current workaround for me is to use the AnimationLayers addon. Extract the bones, then smart merge back down and it fixes it always showing keys for that control... Alternatively deleting all the keys and then readding just one fixes it, but keeping any of the keys from the existing animation as-is keeps the keys always showing. Idk why.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and I manage to solve the issue in my specific case. The problem was in the Drivers Editor there's a pin icon that shows the hint message "Display channel regardless of object selection", and it should be off, for me it was on.

[image]